# External SVG with <use> and load-flash - does file load asynchronously?

Tags: html, css, performance, svg

I've run into a slightly annoying problem in which my `svg` icons loads visibly after the other content on slower devices (when not cached). This causes a "flash of missing/no icons".

The `.svg` icons are combined in an external svg sprite and are fetched by e.g.:

```
<svg class="icon icon-microsoftexcel">
    <use href="/icons/symbol-defs.svg#icon-example" xlink:href="/icons/symbol-defs.svg#icon-example"></use>
</svg>
```

Despite the svg/use being right after the body tag, the file itself is almost always loaded as one of the last files. For instance, it's loaded **after** all images within a certain page is loaded - and these are called considerably further down the DOM tree.

So my question: why aren't the file loaded as soon as the request is found in the DOM tree, and is there anything that can be done to speed it up?

Regarding speed:
I found some suggestions using

```
.body::before{
content: url("/icons/symbol-defs.svg");
display:none;
}
```

However this causes the browser (chrome) to load the `.svg` file 2 times rather than one - and the same applies when trying to "preload" it using a `background-image`.